# PyQt: TableWidget deselect all?

Tags: python, pyqt, qtablewidget, selectall

So, I'm using Python with PyQt and I have a QTableWidget. What I want to do is to, at some point, deselect everything in the QTableWidget. Is there a simple way to do that? I mean, there is a select_all option, but I can't find anything to deselect all...

Comment: what do you mean by deselect?

Comment: Deselect all cells in the TableWidget that might be selected...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should use the [`clearSelection`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemview.html#clearSelection) method on the QTableWidget.

Edit: updated the link towards qt.io.